# Blender 2.8 (python) - adding keywords to a JPEG output file

Tags: python

Is it possible to add descriptive information to a .jpg file - for example, image title, description and keywords?

I am particularly interested in python scripts that would do this.

Thanks!

Comment: `piexif` could be what you're looking for. Blender doesn't offer any options to write custom exif tags.

Comment: will that work as an import/addon/whatever within blender, or do I have to run it outside of blender?

Comment: You would either have to run it externally or create an external script directory that Blender can load which you would then have to add in *Preferences > File Paths > Scripts*. The latter would allow you to import the module in Blender.